# How to let istio resolve self defined hosts

Tags: istio

Scenario:
I have 2 clusters: A and B both with istio installed. I want to expose service-1 in cluster A as service-1.suffix, and let service-2 in cluster B access service-1 by: service-1.suffix. The folloing picture illustrates my idea.
[image]
In cluster A, I define a virtualService and Gateway to route the requests to service-1.

Gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "service-1.suffix"
```

VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  hosts:
  - service-1.default.svc.cluster.local
  - "service-1.suffix"
  gateways:
  - service-1
  - mesh
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: service-1.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
```

This is working fine as I can use curl to access it successfully.

```
curl -I -HHost:service-1.suffix http://cluster_A_proxy:31380
```

The next step is creating Egress and VirtualService in Cluster B. Here are my definition files:

ServiceEntry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  hosts:
  - "service-1.suffix"   #the global suffix mcm.com could be defined in mcm.
  #addresses:
  #- xxx/32
  ports:
  - number: 80   
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: STATIC
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  endpoints:
  - address: 1.1.1.1  #The cluster A proxy ip
    ports:
      http: 31380
```

VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: service-1
spec:
  hosts:
  - "service-1.suffix"
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: "service-1.suffix"
        port:
          number: 80
```

In Cluster B, when I try to use curl to resolve service-1.suffix, I got a DNS error saying this cannot be resolved.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: service-1.suffix
```

How can I fix this?

```
#The command I am using in an istio app in Cluster B:
kubectl exec -it pod_name -c container_name bash
curl -I -HHost:service-1.suffix http://service-1.suffix
```

Edit: 
    When I use another resolvable hostname like www.google.com in serviceentry I can get it through, the requests to www.google.com will be redirected to service-1 in cluster A. Just the same, if I use nip.io as my suffix, it works well. However, the made up name service-1.suffix could not be resolved.

Comment: I have several questions: 1. From where did you try this command `curl -I -HHost:service-1.suffix http://service-1.suffix`? 2. Did you configure the Egress Gateway in the Cluster B?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Hi, I try that command inside  a sleep service in Cluster B. I used kubectl exec to get in.  I didn't configure the Egress Gateway, could you tell me how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Define a Kubernetes [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) service with a random IP:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: then, which host should the pods in cluster B, `service1.<namespace>`(k8s service host) ? or `service-1.suffix`(self defined host)? In fact,  I've tried both, `curl http://service1.<namespace>` and `curl http://service-1.suffix`, both returned with: `Could not resolve host`. BTW, what do you mean by `random iP` ?

Comment: ah, I see, you have to use then `service1.<namespace>` in your ServiceEntry and VirtualService. Random IP - any IP that is not used by Kubernetes, like 127.255.0.2, used in https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/examples/multicluster/gateways/#configure-the-example-services .